Best practice for optional parameter driven SQL queries for use on reports
I am reporting on approximately a million rows of orders for customers.
These orders are for data that needs a lot of calculations, cross referencing and other types of processing. As a result I have written a centralised data retrieval stored procedure that gets the raw order data and performs all the calculations against it (rather than each report including about 1000 lines of T-SQL code to format the data). This keeps the maintenance overhead lower and ensures that data is consistent across a suite of SSRS reports.
In order to provide the correct reporting criteria I have used a parameter block in my stored procedure like this:
WHERE
    (
        (WasteOrderDetail.Active = 1) AND
        (WasteOrderDetail.WasteOrderStatusId IN(2,7,8,9)) AND
        (
            (
                (CAST(WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate AS DATE) >= @LocalStartDate) AND  
                (@LocalStartDate IS NOT NULL) 
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalStartDate IS NULL) 
            )
        ) AND
        (
            (
                (CAST(WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate AS DATE) <= @LocalEndDate) AND
                (@LocalEndDate IS NOT NULL) 
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalEndDate IS NULL) 
            )
        )  AND
        (
            (
                (
                    (ClientHierarchy2.ParentClientId = @LocalClientId) AND
                    (@LocalClientId IS NOT NULL) 
                )
            ) OR
            (
                (
                    (ClientHierarchy1.ParentClientId = @LocalClientId) AND
                    (@LocalClientId IS NOT NULL) 
                )
            ) OR
            (
                (
                    (Site.ClientId = @LocalClientId) AND
                    (@LocalClientId IS NOT NULL) 
                )
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalClientId IS NULL) 
            )
        ) AND
        (
            (
                (WasteOrderHeader.SiteId = @LocalSiteId) AND
                (@LocalSiteId IS NOT NULL) 
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalSiteId IS NULL) 
            )
        ) AND 
        (
            (
                (WasteOrderHeader.WasteOrderHeaderId = @LocalWasteOrderHeaderId) AND
                (@LocalWasteOrderHeaderId IS NOT NULL) 
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalWasteOrderHeaderId IS NULL) 
            )
        ) AND 
        (
            (
                (WasteOrderDetail.WasteOrderDetailId = @LocalWasteOrderDetailId) AND
                (@LocalWasteOrderDetailId IS NOT NULL) 
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalWasteOrderDetailId IS NULL) 
            )
        ) AND 
        (
            (
                (Facility.ContractorId = @LocalContractorId) AND
                (@LocalContractorId IS NOT NULL) 
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalContractorId IS NULL) 
            )
        ) AND 
        (
            (
                (WasteOrderDetail.FacilityId = @LocalFacilityId) AND
                (@LocalFacilityId IS NOT NULL) 
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalFacilityId IS NULL) 
            )
        ) AND 
        (
            (
                (DATEPART(YEAR,WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate) = @LocalYear) AND
                (@LocalYear IS NOT NULL)
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalYear IS NULL)
            )
        ) AND 
        (
            (
                (DATEPART(MONTH,WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate) = @LocalMonth) AND
                (@LocalMonth IS NOT NULL) 
            ) OR
            (
                (@LocalMonth IS NULL)
            )
        ) AND
        (
            (@LocalClientId IS NOT NULL) OR
            (@LocalSiteId IS NOT NULL) OR
            (@LocalWasteOrderHeaderId IS NOT NULL) OR
            (@LocalWasteOrderDetailId IS NOT NULL)  OR
            (@LocalContractorId IS NOT NULL) OR
            (@LocalFacilityId IS NOT NULL) OR
            (@LocalStartDate IS NOT NULL) OR
            (@LocalEndDate IS NOT NULL) OR
            (@LocalYear IS NOT NULL) OR
            (@LocalMonth IS NOT NULL) 
        )
    )

I move the stored procedure input parameters into local parameters to avoid parameter sniffing issues.
This solution is far from ideal as it can cause some issues with the execution plan (I did want to use a view for the centralised retrieval using a CTE but the conditional parameters ruined the performance). I have read that blocks of conditional parameters can be bad but I can see no alternative.
What is the generally accepted solution for providing maintainable and centralised data retrieval when the data requires parameters for selection?

Recommended reading: Catch-all queries (revisited), and A kitchen sink example.

CAST(WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate AS DATE) >= @LocalStartDate)  why is your column ActionDate not already a date and time value? That's a more fundamental issue.

Using a CASE statement in the WHERE clause is an interesting idea. This was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

None of those articles suggest using a CASE expression in the WHERE, @Spencer ... And wrapping a column value in a CASE expression in the WHERE is not a good idea; it'll make the query non-SARGable.

One of the first things you need to fix first is your non-SARGable clauses. It appears that you do have a design flaw, in that your column WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate is not a date (and time) value, as you need to CAST it to a date; that is a fundamental design flaw you need to fix. CASTing a string based column to a date dose not make a SARGable query. If your value is at least sensible, and in the format yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMdd then you can at least treat it like a date and compare it to date strings, which as YourColumn >= '20241230'. If, however, the value isn't in such a format, such as dd/MM/yyyy then you have a severe problem; according to your data 01/01/2025 is *BEFORE 02/01/1945. If that is your design then step one is fixing the design.
Next you have some other non-SARgable clauses, such as (DATEPART(YEAR,WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate) = @LocalYear); this should be done with date boundaries. You can easily get the start and end dates for a year with DATEFROMPARTS:
AND WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@LocalYear,1,1)
AND WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@LocalYear+1,1,1)

Unfortunately there isn't much you can do about (DATEPART(MONTH,WasteOrderDetail.ActionDate) = @LocalMonth) unless you consider using a calendar table; dates aren't arrange in month order first so an INDEX on WasteOrderDetail isn't going to be helpful. If you do have a calendar table (and you JOIN to it), then you could filter on the CalendarMonth column, which could have an index on it. This would also work for the year filter.
Finally you have you overall query. You could just "throw" an OPTION (RECOMPILE) at the end (after fixing the SARGable clauses as best you can) and see how the query does. You might well find that there are improvements even with the cost of recreating the plan each time. You might, however, considering removing the final clause where you check at least one parameter isn't NULL, and instead adding that as a check at the start of the query and THROWing an error if it isn't; this gives the end user a meaningful error rather than an empty result set if they don't pass any values:
IF (@LocalClientId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalSiteId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalWasteOrderHeaderId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalWasteOrderDetailId IS NOT NULL  AND 
                        @LocalContractorId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalFacilityId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalStartDate IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalEndDate IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalYear IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalMonth IS NOT NULL)
    THROW 59812, N'At least one parameter must have a non-NULL value.', 10; --Choose an error number appropriate for you, I just used an arbitrary one

If you find that the the cost of using OPTION (RECOMPILE) is too much, then the next "port of call" would be to use dynamic SQL and create a parametrised query that only passes the parameters that aren't NULL. Considering this is coming from SSRS, you'll want to call the procedure with a WITH RESULTS SETS, otherwise you'll need to provide SSRS with some "sample" parameters so it can get a sample result set. Your queries in the stored procedure could look something like this:
IF (@LocalClientId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalSiteId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalWasteOrderHeaderId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalWasteOrderDetailId IS NOT NULL  AND 
                        @LocalContractorId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalFacilityId IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalStartDate IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalEndDate IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalYear IS NOT NULL AND 
                        @LocalMonth IS NOT NULL)
    THROW 59812, N'At least one parameter must have a non-NULL value.', 10;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ...' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM ...' + @CRLF + 
           N'WHERE WOD.Active = 1' + @CRLF + --WOD for WasteOrderDetail; use aliases.
           N'  AND WOD.WasteOrderStatusId IN (2,7,8,9)' + 
           CASE WHEN @LocalClientId IS NOT NULL THEN @CRLF + N'  AND @LocalClientId IN (CH2.ParentClientId, CH1.ParentClientId, S.ClientId)' ELSE N'' END +
           CASE WHEN @LocalSiteId IS NOT NULL THEN @CRLF + N'  AND WOH.SiteId = @LocalSiteId' ELSE N'' END +
           CASE WHEN @LocalYear IS NOT NULL THEN @CRLF + N'  AND WOH.ActionDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@LocalYear,1,1)' + @CRLF +
                                                         N'  AND WOH.ActionDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@LocalYear+1,1,1)' ELSE N'' END + ...
           + N';';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@LocalClientId <data type>, @LocalSiteId <data type>, .., @LocalYear int, @LocalMonth int', @LocalClientId, @LocalSiteId, ..., @LocalMonth;

Then, as mentioned, when you execute your procedure, you would need to use WITH RESULT SETS:
EXEC dbo.YourProceure @LocalClientId, @LocalSiteId, ..., @LocalMonth
WITH RESULT SETS ((ClientID int, SiteID int, ...);


Wow - you live and learn, I never saw WITH RESULT SETS before. I've always used the if 1 = 0 select columnlist; approach which I can't even find a reference to now, but is great because it allows one to define the returned resultset without running the logic inside the SP rather than defining the resultset here where you call the SP.
